# Filter a host so it appears like closed and unfiltered to scanners

Tags: iptables, firewall, port-scanning

I want to filter traffic coming into my Linux box so ports appears like closed instead of "filtered".

Using iptables, except for ports I intended to open (`-j ACCEPT`), I have done the following on `INPUT` traffic (IPv4):

- For established or related connections (using `-m conntrack`), ignore and accept
- For TCP, `-j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`, which should send a TCP RST packet back
- For UDP, reject with `icmp-port-unreachable`
- For ICMP, accept echo request (so it can be pinged), and respond with `icmp-proto-unreachable`
- For everything else (protocols except 1, 6 and 17), respond with `icmp-proto-unreachable`

For IPv6, everythinge except TCP is rejected with `icmp6-port-unreachable`. I haven't filtered any `OUTPUT` traffic.

Should I take any extra actions or is the setup comprehensive enough?

Comment: http://shouldiblockicmp.com/

Comment: @user253751 As far as I'm aware of, ICMP types like "fragmentation needed" and TLE are covered by Linux conntrack module (so I don't have to explicitly allow echo-responses). That's why I only allow echo-request - it's (supposedly) the only message type that can originate from the outside (IPv4). For IPv6, I agree that RA and NA should both be allowed, in addition to echo-request.